# How to model entity types that can contain each other?

Tags: database-design

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to model a database with a Many-to-Many relationship between a concept of *Markets* & regions of the world.

The issue I'm running into is that a *Market* is just a region for doing business. It could be *North America*, and include multiple cities, provinces, and countries, or it could be the city of Ottawa, Ontario, Canada. Meaning, a *Market* can contain many regions, or regions can contain many *Markets*.

I've seen some structures for this concept with a separation between a *Global Market* which would be ones that include more than one country, and a *Regional Market* which would be only within one country. But this is treating them as two different entities when, by nature, they're the same.

Is there a standard model for structuring data that could efficiently convey the parent in the relationship? To easily be able to say `The North American Market contains these countries`, which would enable deriving provinces & cities, but also say `The USA contains these Markets` or `Texas contains these Markets.`